# Image button with hover state

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble to make an image button, It doesn't display properly.

HTML

```
<div class="icon">
   <a role="button"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.icon{
background: url('assets/icon.png')
}
.icon:hover{
background: url('assets/icon-hover.png')
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: can you add a more complete version of the html and css code into a js  fiddle for us to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is related to the div not having any content. Try adding a width and height to the div that matches the dimensions of the icon.png

```
.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: If you just want to use css you would have to provide different widths and heights at the breakpoints you are supporting

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use div as a button (it's not clickable), single `<a>` will suffice.

```
<a href='#' class="btn">Button</a>
```

Depending on your goal you might want to use `<button>`
For when to use what see: https://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/

Since you have link without text, it won't show anything as background; as @PatrickKelly mentioned you need to set width and height and change display to inline block because by default `<a>` is inline.

```
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px; 
}
```

Having image links/buttons without text is bad for accessibility (screen readers). See 13 here: https://www.sitepoint.com/15-rules-making-accessible-links/